# Retrieving Last Inserted ROWID In PHP/OCI

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Is it possible to retrieve the rowid of the last inserted Oracle row in PHP? I was trying:

```
$statement = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO myTable (...) VALUES ( ...)");
$results = oci_execute($statement);
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
    $rowid = $row['ROWID'];
}
```

With no luck. I'm getting the error **define not done before fetch or execute and fetch** at the fetch line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare:

```
$var = "AAAV1vAAGAAIb4CAAC";
```

Use:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (...) VALUES ( ...)
RETURNING RowId INTO :p_val
```

Bind your variable to a PHP variable:

```
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":p_val", $val, 18);
```

Comment: Hey Ben,

I'm getting the following error:
`Query Failed: 

INSERT INTO testtable (ABC) VALUES (6) RETURNING RowId INTO :id`

I followed everything in your post. Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: @Tom i guess it should be "INSERT INTO testtable (ABC) VALUES (6) RETURNING ***ABC*** INTO :id" since it seem's RowId column doesn't exists on testtable

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer was not really clear to me because it lacks some important information I will point out a similar approach.

In your SQL statement, add the `RETURNING INTO`clause.

```
$statement = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO myTable (...) VALUES ( ...) RETURNING ID INTO :id");
```

Here `ID` is the name of the column you want to return. Before executing the `$statement`, you need to bind a PHP variable to your return value. Here I used `$returnId` (you don't need to declare it beforehand or assign any default value).

```
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":id", $returnId);
```

Only **after** binding the variable, the statement can be executed.

```
$success = @oci_execute($statement);
```

`$returnId` now has the value of the `ID` column inserted previously.

Comment: you should specify the size and type of your variable on the bind funcion like:   oci_bind_by_name($statement, ":id", $returnId, -1, SQLT_INT);
otherwise you'd experiment some strange incomplete-variable-value issues. for example, instead of ID=12345 you'd get ID=1234 or something.