# How to match auto increment from table 1 into table 2 in POST method PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, oracle11g

how are you doing?

I'm using PHP and Oracle 11g database.

I have 2 Post's and 2 Insert's in different tables as below:

```
//Insert 1:

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      $nome = strtoupper($_POST['nome']);
      $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
      $data_nasc = $_POST['datanasc'];
      $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

// Insert 2:

$cpf2 = $_POST['cpf'];
      $curso1 = $_POST['curso1'];
      $and1 = $_POST['and1'];
      $nins1 = strtoupper($_POST['nins1']);


// Query 1:

 $query = "insert into selecao_candidatos_site (nome, sexo, data_nasc, cpf)
      values ('$nome', '$sexo', '$data_nasc', '$cpf')";
   

// Query 2:
   
 $query2 = "insert into SELECAO_CAND_FORM_SITE (cpf, curso1, and1, nins1) values 
('$cpf2', '$curso1', '$and1', '$nins1')";
      

// Executing SQL:

      $s=oci_parse($bConectado, $query);
      $s2=oci_parse($bConectado, $query2);
      oci_execute ($s);
      oci_execute($s2);

  }
```

The 1st table has an ID that auto increments itself. I'm trying to take this ID value from the oracle database, and insert the same value on the 2nd table, to match both tables.

I tried putting this code after POST on table 1, and before POST on table 2 but didn't worked out.

```
 $sqle = "select max(id) from selecao_candidatos_site";
      $result = oci_parse($conn,$sqle);
      oci_execute ($result);
```

How can I take the auto increment ID from table 1, store it in a variable, and insert in table 2?

I'm almost 2 days on it and searching for hours, any help would really be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, parameterize your query. MySQL is not being used, right? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335113/retrieving-last-inserted-rowid-in-php-oci is relevant?

Comment: Hi. Didn't work because i'm not including ID in the POST method. ID is in the database only.

Comment: Updating. It worked. All i had to do was follow Tobias Kaufmann's POST and the complement by @ThatsMe on this very nice link. Thank you all. Very useful.